# I was looking for a default U-boot configuration for BeagleBone Black. I cannot find am335x_boneblack_defconfig inside u-boot/configs/ folder

Tags: linux, embedded, embedded-linux, bootloader, u-boot

The old versions show am335x_boneblack_defconfig(branch v2017.01 instead of the master) file inside the directory but I am not able to see it in the newer version.So which branch should I use to build U-Boot for BeagleBone Black? Under boards/ti/am335x/, I saw that am335x_* can be used for BeagleBone Black. Any help will be appreciated?

Comment: I want to know which configuration file should I use to build the bootloader?

Comment: here is the u-boot directoy which I cloned : git://git.denx.de/u-boot.git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `configs/am335x_evm_defconfig` - see line 36:

```
CONFIG_OF_LIST="am335x-evm am335x-bone am335x-boneblack am335x-evmsk am335x-bonegreen am335x-icev2 am335x-pocketbeagle"
```

You will find a confirmation, along with at lof of interesting information, [here](https://www.digikey.com/eewiki/display/linuxonarm/BeagleBone+Black#BeagleBoneBlack-Bootloader).