# SPL and U-Boot placement

Tags: u-boot, spl

Storage device for an embedded system is organized as:

- Non-partitioned space, saved for U-Boot.
- BOOT-VAR6UL - A FAT16 partition containing the Linux image and the device tree blob/s.
- "rootfs" - An ext4 partition containing the root file system (including the kernel modules).

Last two storage "space" are partitioned for BOOT and filesystem, in the format requested (FAT16 or ext4).
Space for SPL and u-boot is defined as "Non-partitioned space": is there someone who can explain the reason of this?
A further question: surfing in a SD card or in eMMC memory I'm able to check which files are stored in the partitioned spaces.
How can I see or check SPL or u-boot?  Is this not possible?
Paolo

Comment: *"'Non-partitioned space': ... the reason of this?"* -- Provides for simpler access and less code & data => a smaller binary image.  A filesystem is an added layer for flexible data organization that would require more code in the form of a library to support that filesystem.   "Non-partitioned space" would instead simply use preassigned, fixed sector locations for storing boot images.  For an example see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60873038/how-to-write-new-mlo-and-u-boot-img-to-an-sd-card-without-erasing-the-os/60880147#60880147 (MLO is just a SPL with a header)

Answer (score 0):

Making some assumptions based on what you say, `BOOT-VAR6UL` implies to me that you're on an NXP i.MX6UL-based system.  If you look up the manuals for that SoC it will describe where it looks on eMMC (and, SD card) memory for binaries to boot.  These areas will in turn often be marked as "non-partitioned space" or otherwise reserved so that the OS installer doesn't overwrite that part of the firmware.  This is true of most SoCs and the locations will change from vendor to vendor, but less often with SoCs from the same semiconductor.

Answer (score -1):

1. The reason to locate SPL and Proper in non-partitioned space is limited abilities of SoCs built-in firmware. Realizing support of partiton table(s) and filesystem(s) in firmware requires more ROM. Some of SoCs, for example, are so limited that they can not boot from SATA (while controller is implemented on SoC) - and boot from SD and/or NAND only with direct access only.
2. Yes you can see or check SPL and U-Boot Proper if you know blocks they are located in by using dd (same as you write boots to SD-card or any other device).

Comment: Very interesting, Daft Soft.
Coudl you give me further details about how yo use dd to check SPL and U-Boot?
Thanks

Comment: Every SoC has it's built in BootROM - a small firmware with very limited functionality. BootROM has it's own boot addresses hardcoded.
You need to see manual for your SoC to know exact blocks it loads from. You can see how your manufacturer guides you to write it's boot block (some times it's consist not only of U-Boot).
For example, if your manual tells something like: dd if=flash.bin of=/dev/sdX seek=offset bs=block_size. From this you can grab your bootblock back to a regular file by just swapping "of" and "if" and replacing "seek" with "skip".
Then examine file you get from dd.